# when concatenating more than one field in iif clause condition showing error in SSRS report builder 2016

Tags: ssrs-2016

When i do concatenation of more than one field in if true clues it showing error. my expression code as as below:

```
=IIf(Fields!testnm.Value="High Temperature Test","Temperature Tolerance :"&Fields!val1.Value&" "&"Duration :"&Fields!val2.Value&" "&"Remarks :"&Fields!val3.Value,
IIf(Fields!testnm.Value="Burn In Test","Temperature Tolerance :"&Fields!val1.Value&" "&"Duration :"&Fields!val2.Value&" "&"Remarks :"&Fields!val3.Value,
IIf(Fields!testnm.Value="Low Temperature Test","Temperature Tolerance :"&Fields!val1.Value&" "&"Duration :"&Fields!val2.Value&" "&"Remarks :"&Fields!val3.Value,
IIf(Fields!testnm.Value="Dump Heat Test","Temperature Tolerance :"&Fields!val1.Value&" "&"RH Tolerance ""&Fields!val2.Value&" "&"Duration :"&Fields!val3.Value&" "&"Remarks :"&Fields!val4.Value,
IIf(Fields!testnm.Value="Rendom Vibration Test","Frequency Range :"&Fields!val1.Value&" "&"BreakUp  Details :"&Fields!val2.Value&" "&"duration :"&Fields!val3.Value&" "&"Vibration Axis :"&Fields!val4.Value&" "&"Remarks :"&Fields!val5.Value&,
IIf(Fields!testnm.Value="Shock Test","Amplitude :"&Fields!val1.Value&" "&"Pulse Duration :"&Fields!val2.Value&" "&"Shocks :"&Fields!val3.Value&" "&"Wave :"&Fields!val4.Value&" "&"Shock Axis :"&Fields!val5.Value&" "&"Remarks :"&Fields!val6.Value,
IIf(Fields!testnm.Value="Sine Vibration Test","Frequency Range :"&Fields!val1.Value&" "&"BreakUp Details :"&Fields!val2.Value&" "&"Duration :"&Fields!val3.Value&" "&"Endurance :"&Fields!val4.Value&" "&"Sweeps :"&Fields!val5.Value&" "&"Endurance Duration :"&Fields!val6.Value&" "&"Vibration Axis :"&Fields!val7.Value&" "&"Remarks :"&Fields!val8.Value,
IIf(Fields!testnm.Value="Thermal Cycling Test","Temperature Tolerance To :"&Fields!val1.Value&" "&"From :"&Fields!val2.Value&" "&"Soak for PTemp :"&Fields!val3.Value&" "&"Soak for NTemp :"&Fields!val4.Value&" "&"Cooling Rate :"&Fields!val5.Value&" "&"Cycles :"&Fields!val6.Value&" "&"Remarks :"&Fields!val7.Value,
IIf(Fields!testnm.Value="Thermal Shock Test","Temperature Tolerance To :"&Fields!val1.Value&" "&"From :"&Fields!val2.Value&" "&"Changeover Time :"&Fields!val3.Value&" "&"Soak Duration :"&Fields!val4.Value&" "&"Cycles :"&Fields!val5.Value&" "&"Remarks :"&Fields!val6.Value,"BreakUp Details :"&Fields!val1.Value&" "&"RH Tolerance :"&Fields!val2.Value&" "&"Cycles :"&Fields!val3.Value&" "&"Remarks :"&Fields!val4.Value)))))))))
```

can anyone guide .. appreciate your guidance

Comment: It looks like it should be working. Are there multiple val*x* values for a single textnm? Have you tried running it in the VS Preview and see what the Error Message says?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of line 5 you have an extra & Or am I missing the why of it being there?